# Error in importing xwlt package

Tags: python

I am getting the below error even after doing a python setup.py install for xlwt.

ImportError: No Module named xlwt

I have tried installing using python wheel

pip3 install xlwt-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

and I have also tried easy_installer, however the error is still there

What might be the issue?

I am using a windows 7 environment.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: ImportError: No Module named xlwt

Comment: can you double check the interpreter version on u executing the code, as you installed pckg on python3

Comment: Try to install it from the Git repository `pip3 install https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/archive/master.zip
`

Comment: after install you can verify if installed or not by command pip3 freeze

Comment: @Roushan the python version is 3.6

Comment: Output of the freeze command: $ pip3 freeze
xlwt==1.3.0. However the error remains import xlwt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlwt'. It seems that even after install the script is not able to find the xlwt package. What should be checked in this case?

Answer (score -1):

Command instruction to install xlwt:

```
pip install xlwt
```

Comment: @tan tried to install on pip3 and he already tried to install using wheel

Comment: Try cleaning python installation. Erase manually python directory and reinstall it in the same location. Then retry: pip install xlwt

Comment: cannot use pip install xlwt, proxy is blocked. That is why I downloaded the wheel file and then tried it by using: pip install <location>.whl